# Counting rows that contain a NULL value

Tags: python, null, row

I am looking at doing a Data Quality assessment and I would like to see what proportion of records contain a NULL value somewhere. I know I can use `data.isnull()` to give a boolean for where there are NULLs and I can do something like `data.isnull().sum()` to give me the total number of NULL values per column. If I want to do this per row however, I imagine I might need to use a loop. Something like this

```
for i in data:
    if i isnull() ......
```

This is clearly wrong however and I am now aware of my ignorance and lost.

It would be good to be able to create a flag at the end of the column that contains either a boolean or a 1 or 0 for whether or not a NULL was found on that row.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `pandas` you can just do `df.isnull().sum(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @EdChum.

I can indeed simply type

```
data.isnull().sum(1)
```

This gives the total number of NULL values found on each row with the axis being given by the `1` in `sum(1)`